# Optional parameters in R function

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function in R that takes either a data.frame *or* a file path, leading to a csv that would be read in as a data.frame.

I currently have this:

```
occInput <- function(fileInput, dfInput = NA) {  
  if (is.na(dfInput)) occ.dat <- read.csv(file = fileInput)
  else occ.dat <- dfInput

  #manipulate the data in occ.dat
}
```

However, when I actually pass in a data.frame as the `dfInput` parameter, it throws the warning:

> Warning in `if (is.na(dfInput)) occ.dat <- read.csv(file = fileInput)
>   else occ.dat <- dfInput`:   the condition has length > 1 and only the
>   first element will be used

While this does not actually adversely affect my code, it's ugly, and it suggests to me that there is a more *elegant* way to have either/or optional arguments in a function.

**Any suggestions?** I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: I think checking for `is.null(dfInput)` is an better option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not trust on `NA` when argument is expected to get value as `data.frame`, `list` etc. `is.na` returns NA check for each element to those data structures. The better option could be to initialize your argument with `NULL` and check with `is.NULL`. Another option could be to use `missing` function on `dfInput` argument. Your function definition can be written as:

```
occInput <- function(fileInput, dfInput = NULL) {  
  if (is.NULL(dfInput)) occ.dat <- read.csv(file = fileInput)
  else occ.dat <- dfInput

  #manipulate the data in occ.dat
}

#OR you can just use missing function

occInput <- function(fileInput, dfInput) {  
  #Perform missing check
  if (missing(dfInput)) occ.dat <- read.csv(file = fileInput)
  else occ.dat <- dfInput

  #manipulate the data in occ.dat
}
```

Comment: Thanks, `missing()` is exactly what I needed. Much less hacky than what I was trying to do...

Answer (score 1):

Why have two arguments? Just have one and test if its data-framey:

```
occInput <- function(Input) {  
  if (!inherits(Input,"data.frame")){
    # its not a data frame, so treat as a file name...
    Input = read.csv(Input)
  }
  # Now Input is a data frame...
}
```

works with data frames, data tables, and tibbles.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one (slightly hacky) way to do it: use `if (identical(dfInput, NA))` rather than `if (is.na(dfInput))`, which does not throw any errors, as it checks whether the two arguments are *identical* rather than equivalent.

However, it still doesn't seem very elegant to me. I'll leave the question unsolved in case someone else wants to take a better stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

if does only check the first element of a vector otherwise you get mentioned warning.

Checking the `class` of the passed argument is quite more error tolerant:

```
occInput <- function(fileInput, dfInput = NA) {  
  if ("data.frame" %in% class(dfInput)) print("dfInput contains a data.frame") # read.csv(file = fileInput)
}

> occInput("adsf")
> occInput("adsf", "asdf")
> occInput("adsf", NULL)
> occInput("adsf", 1:10)
> occInput(dfInput = as.data.frame(mtcars))
[1] "dfInput contains a data.frame"
```